# execute immediate update doesn't put value PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Im trying to update values in PL SQL. The problem is that my dbms_output.put_line is working fine, everything is writen good, but execute immediate doesn't work. The funny thing is, that it works once (or even two) but now it doesn't work. I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Program that i write is inserting some random values into table that is created from values that are input veriables. code can be little to long to be throwed here, i put the most important part of code

```
for looper in 1..y loop
         execute immediate 'insert into GAME ' || s_string || ' values ' 
         || rowGenerator(v_low=>1, v_high=>6, v_x=>x);
         end loop;

         start_x_point:= round (dbms_random.value( high=>x, low=>1));
         start_y_point:= round (dbms_random.value( high=>y, low=>1));
         dbms_output.put_line(start_x_point || ' ' || start_y_point);
         s_temp:= ' set x' || start_x_point || ' = 0 where ROWNUM = '|| start_y_point; 
         dbms_output.put_line(s_temp);
         execute immediate 'update GAME ' || s_temp;
```

s_string conteining bracket with columns,

rowGenerator insert random values into table,

start_x_point and start_y_point is the place where i want to put 0 value

and the problem is that it doesn't works. I don't know other way to do that.

that is how my table looks like after puting random values, its a matrix with values

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8
1   2   5   3   2   4   1   1   3
2   2   3   2   5   4   5   3   3
3   4   3   4   2   4   2   6   3
4   2   1   1   4   3   2   4   1
5   1   5   2   5   3   3   5   4
6   1   5   5   1   1   3   5   3
7   5   3   3   4   4   3   1   3
8   5   4   5   6   3   4   3   2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your problem is `ROWNUM = ...`. It'll work only when `START_Y_POINT = 1`, and won't work when it is not.

What to do? Don't use `ROWNUM`; `UPDATE` values that depend on something else (some `ID` value, perhaps?).

Comment: reffering to your edit msg, i don't have id in that table and it can't have it.

Comment: Well, I don't know *what* you have (you never shared that info with us); I just tried to *guess* (and failed).

Comment: i added how table is looks like after puting values, now with two random values i want to update x-> column and y-> row by 0 value.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Littlefoot i got answer!

i just need to put something like that

```
select * from (select * from game
where rownum <=start_y_point 
order by rownum desc)
where rownum=1;
```

and i getting the row that i want!